# Maven does not generate the jar file inside the target folder of my Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am working on a Spring Boot application with Maven: when I use `mvn package` or `mvn install` the target folder and the class file of my project are created but the jar is not created.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the build output:

```
PS C:\Users\PBD1BAN\Downloads\demo> mvn package
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] 'profiles.profile[artifactory].repositories.repository.id' must be unique but found duplicate repository with id maven-central-libs-snapsh
ots @ C:\Users\PBD1BAN\.m2\settings.xml
[WARNING]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug release 17] to target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.734 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-23T16:14:20+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I need to compile into jar file so that I can create a docker image and run the code inside the image using `java -jar demo.jar`.

Comment: Remove the `version` from the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. You are using a version which is not compatible. The version should match the version of Spring Boot you are using and in your case is managed by the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `repackage` goal:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

From the documentation:

> Repackage existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed from the command
> line using {@literal java -jar}. With <code>layout=NONE</code> can also be used simply
> to package a JAR with nested dependencies (and no main class, so not executable).

Comment: Thanks for your Information. When I run mvn package it throwing Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> error.